# How do you handle url changes/page switches in Dart?

Tags: gwt, dart, dart-polymer

I cannot tell if Google Dart is designed to create "single-page" apps like GWT or if you are meant to mix and match a bunch of html pages using traditional links and redirects.

In my previous application (written in GWT) everything that was a page switch just changed the url after # meaning there was never really a roundtrip to the server.  GWT Code-splitting asside it was "one page".

Anybody know of documentation how to to handle different pages and switching between them in dart?

Answer (score 1):

You can build single-page apps in Dart, as well as traditional multi-page server routed apps.

If you want to implement a single-page app in Dart, you can either build the entire capability in yourself, mix and match a couple of different packages to get the effect, or use a single "batteries-included" framework that handles it all for you.

For instance, you could use the [route](https://github.com/dart-lang/route) package to define your routes and then handle the view switching yourself, by swapping out a main "content" area (this will probably be easier if you use Polymer here).

Or if you want a full-fledged framework, you can take a look at [angular.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart) which will take care of routing as well actually switching the view for you.

And of course, if you wanted to build the whole thing out yourself for some reason, you could manually update the hash fragment location or push new History states, and keep track of what view to display.